# React Typescript кодогенерация div в div'е

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

не могу найти конкретный кодовый пример для React Typescript, который мог бы сгенерировать div, затем один/несколько div'ов в нём, затем повторно. Данные (айдишники) должен брать из массива.

Что-то наподобие:

```
<div> (уже существующий div)
    <div id="element1">
        <div id="element11"></div>
        <div id="element12"></div>
        <div id="element13"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="element2">
        <div id="element22"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="element3">
        <div id="element31"></div>
        <div id="element32"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "не могу найти конкретный кодовый пример" - а где ваши попытки? И как выглядит у вас массив, на основе которого надо всё это сгенерировать?

Comment: Похоже на вашу задачу [по рендеру массива в массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1474791/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-map/1474801#1474801)?

Comment: @SwaD да, благодарю за пример. Раньше я не понимал, почему он не видит вложенный массив, поэтому задал вопрос. В этом же примере он в первой мапе указал вложенный массив, который мне и нужен был.